# Cython convert python array to vector[char]

Tags: python-3.x, cython

In python, I make a call to a `calculate` function inn my `pyx` file, which then calls other `cdef` functions.

python function:

```
def getCoord():
   array = ['A','B','C','D']
   px = 5
   py = 6
   move = pyxFile.calculateCoord( array, x, y )
```

pyx function:

```
def calculateCoord( array, px, py):
   cdef vector[ char ] b

   for i in range( len( array) ):
      b.push_back( array[ i ] )

   return search( b, px, py )
```

I'm trying to pass a python array of characters to a `vector[char]` for use in my cdef functions, but my error is `an integer is required` on the line `b.push_back( array[ i ] )`

`x` and `y` are integers

`search` (a cdef function) returns a tuple of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs are length-1 strings rather than chars. I know this seems like it should be identical, but it isn't.

You can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to get the integer value of a length-1 string:

```
  b.push_back( ord(array[ i ]) )
```